# Office chair: use the backrest or not

Tags: ergonomics

I'm currently test driving and reviewing a new chair. The salesman recommended that I should not use the back support, but sit a bit to to the front and rely on my lower back muscles. This position seems to work for me, but I cannot sustain it for long periods of time.

So I was wondering whether there is any research related to the effects on the back of typing in a computer for long periods of time, without using back support.

Comment: Is this about posture or level of personal fitness?

Comment: While Steelcase obviously want to sell you stuff, they do have [a lot of ergonomics-related research](https://www.steelcase.com/research/topics/ergonomics/) on their website, much of which is heavy on citations. Not sure if your specific use-case is covered, but worth a look.

Comment: You should have offered half price for the chair as the back is just an ornament.

Comment: About posture @SolarMike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This position seems to work for me, but I cannot sustain it for long periods of time.

That is absolutely normal. Our bodies (bodies of animals included) are not made to be kept motionless for a long time.

The best example: even during sleep (the most motionless time), we turn from one side to the other.

Another way of thinking: if the backrest would be so dangerous, the manufacturer would not install it and would sell more chairs, cheaper. It would be illegal for any chairs to have a backrest.

Of course, a bad posture on any chair can create health problems, but being careful about it will avoid you getting in trouble.

---

On the other hand, if the person has specific health problems (e.g., spine-related), then special recommendations from a doctor must be followed.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for not using a backrest would probably be reading on articles related to [kneeling chairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneeling_chair) - which do not include a backrest by design.

Speaking from personal experience, for a period of few weeks my home PC was set up such that I used it standing. I could sustain it for a few hours at most, but the pain didn't feel like the damaging kind but rather like the muscles were just tired.

Comment: The concept looks very interesting, at least as an alternate chare to the main one. I wonder what is the effect of that chair on the knees - they seem to take a lot of stress. Do you have any experience? I might want to try it myself - if I manage to find one to buy.

Comment: @virolino my friend owns one and from the brief usage I didn't really feel any adverse effects and I have mild issues with my knees. While not well known, they are not that rare - IKEA has them for example.

Comment: A great thing is also a sit/stand desk, but the motorized ones are quite expensive. And you need to take great care with your cables management.

Comment: yes, they are great, but their price is even greater :( I dream to have one for a long time, but it has not become reality yet.

Comment: @virolino they are expensive, yes. Depends on how much time you spend in front of a PC at home. I'd liken it to spending money on a good bed if it's a lot

Comment: Oh, yes, a good bed is a Godsend, always.